# JSTestDriver and Continuous Integration

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, hudson, js-test-driver

I am trying to use JSTestDriver to automate my Javascript tests with Hudson as the Continuous Integration backend.  I'm aiming to get Hudson to at least produce a report on the test results, with failing a build upon failed test as the most desirable outcome.

I did a quick search on the web, and found that Hudson doesn't appear to have a direct plugin for JSTestDriver (it only has one for TeamCity).  I was thinking of using Hudson to monitor the javascript tests as an external job, but I have a feeling that this is more complex than required.

Does anyone have experience with/advice to the above scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the xUnit plugin cover you?

In general, Hudson testing plugins do not run the tests - you build script should run the tests itself.  Then Hudson picks up the report that is generated, and renders it nicely in the Hudson UI.

Answer (score 6):

Found this article that was recently published on this topic. Looks like Hudson supports JsTestDriver via its core functionality. You just have to know how to configure it.

http://cjohansen.no/en/javascript/javascript_continuous_integration_with_hudson_and_jstestdriver

Answer (score 1):

Try this thread: [Unable to get hudson to parse JUnit test output XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428553/unable-to-get-hudson-to-parse-junit-test-output-xml)

Basically jstestdriver generates you JUnit-compliant XML results, when you may further use in your CI system of choice.