# Trac won't parse google test xml output files

Tags: c++, junit, trac, googletest

I have run the my unit tests written with the google test 1.6.0 framework with the --gtest_output="xml:test-results.xml" flag and get a test result file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="8" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="81.396" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="TestSuite1" tests="8" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="81.396">
    <testcase name="Test1" status="run" time="6.391" classname="Class1" />
    <testcase name="Test2" status="run" time="6.1" classname="Class1" />
    <testcase name="Test3" status="run" time="7.146" classname="Class1" />
    <testcase name="Test4" status="run" time="16.164" classname="Class1" />
    <testcase name="Test5" status="run" time="25.145" classname="Class1" />
    <testcase name="Test6" status="run" time="6.099" classname="Class1" />
    <testcase name="Test7" status="run" time="6.162" classname="Class1" />
    <testcase name="Test8" status="run" time="8.187" classname="Class1" />
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Based on what I have read in other posts the gtest xml output is supposed to be compatible with junit parsers. Related Post: [Unable to get hudson to parse JUnit test output XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428553/unable-to-get-hudson-to-parse-junit-test-output-xml)

The other possibility of error is in my bitten script.  Running on Trac 0.12.2.  Here is my bitten recipe for parsing the XML file using the java:junit parser:

```
<build xmlns:java="http://bitten.edgewall.org/tools/java">

   <step id="parse_results" description="Gather Results" onerror="fail">  
     <java:junit file="/home/user/temp/test-results.xml" />
   </step>

</build>
```

In trac, it says that the build was successful, but the test results are blank.  0 run, 0 failed, 0 ignored, 0 errors

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.  It turns out that Trac's JUnit parser has a bug.  It doesn't like the testsuites tag and it doesn't like having multiple testsuite sections. PHP allows the testsuites tag, but will not do multiple files.  I chose to create a parser in Python that creates multiple XML files from the Gtest output file.

```
def move_results(results, results_dir):
    # Moves all results into a temp folder to be consumed by Bitten
    # Files with multiple test suite sections, split into individual files
    for files in results:
        fin = open(files)
        test_id = 0
        split_line = files.split('/')
        file_name = split_line[len(split_line)-1].split('.xml')
        for line in fin:
            if not 'testsuites' in line:
                if '<testsuite ' in line:
                    output_file = results_dir + file_name[0] + '-' + str(test_id) + '.xml'
                    test_id = test_id + 1
                    fout = open(output_file, 'w')
                    fout.write('<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n')
                    fout.write(line)
                elif '<testsuite\\>' in line:
                    fout.write(line)
                    fout.close()
                elif not '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n' in line:
                    fout.write(line)
        fin.close()
        os.remove(files)
```

Alternatively, you could use Bitten to do convert using an XSLT.  Also you could combine the output files into a single output (with something like nose's XUnit output) and use `php:phpunit` to parse the file.